# Maven searching artifacts only in SNAPSHOT repository

Tags: java, build, dependencies, repository, maven-3

I have a Maven project which contains the following `dependencyManagement` section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myBom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In my Maven `settings.xml` file, I have the following `repositories` definition:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>public</name>
            <url><pathToArtifactory>/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>public-snapshots</name>
            <url><pathToArtifactory>/public-snapshots</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
Project Build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact myGroup:myBom:pom:1.0.0 in snapshots (<pathToArtifactory>/public-snapshots)
```

After having ran a `mvn dependency:list-repositories`, I can confirm the repositories are correctly defined, and not somewhere overriden.

Why is Maven looking for a `1.0.0` Version into my SNAPSHOT defined repository?

Comment: I recommend to read the docs about repositories in settings.xml https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it !!
Seems that from Maven 3.5.0 onward, having a server id called `central` in `settings.xml` is causing problem with the official Maven Central Repository which is as well called `central`.

Answer (score 1):

Maven searches your snapshot repository for releases.
To disable that behaviour, add the following to the snapshot repository in your `settings.xml` and see if it works:

```xml
<releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</releases>
```

[source](https://smarterco.de/java-maven-add-snapshot-repository-to-pom/)

Also, adding Artifactory as a [mirror](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) instead of a repository should be better. Though I don't know how you'd add snapshots that way.

Comment: I tried that already, should have mentioned, but it didn't help.